# KeyCloak replaces double slash with single slash on redirection

Tags: angular, routes, keycloak, slash

I'm using **Angular** in client side and **KeyCloak** as identity and access management solution.

I have a restricted a **route** like this:
`http://localhost:4200/path/to/component/(outlet1:A//outlet2:B)`

when I want to see this route it will be redirected to KeyCloak to ask credentials, `redirect_uri` query param have been set correctly as well, till now everything is OK. **PROBLEM** is where KeyCloak redirect me back to my Angular app where replaces `//` with `/` in my url (`http://localhost:4200/path/to/component/(outlet1:A/outlet2:B)`) which is not valid on my Angular routes! in other routes which have not double slash there is not any issue!

Why KeyCloak does this? Is it a **Bug** with KeyCloak?

Comment: What is your redirect_uri ?

Comment: Try to pass already urlencoded value to `redirect_uri` parameter, e.g. `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fcomponent%2F%28outlet1%3AA%2F%2Foutlet2%3AB%29`, not just plain text value. There should be a urldecoding/urlencoding on the Keycloak side, which may have a problem.

Comment: @JanGaraj I've checked it before, url encoded correctly by keycloak according to what is see in keycloak URL. problem is something related to its redirection process!

Comment: @dreamcrash correct url is `http://localhost:4200/path/to/component/(outlet1:A//outlet2:B)`, keycloak changes it to `http://localhost:4200/path/to/component/(outlet1:A/outlet2:B)` before redirect back to my app

Comment: @MostafaBita what happens if you change it to http://localhost:4200/path/to/component/(outlet1:A*outlet2:B) ?

Comment: @dreamcrash this is Angular strategy to handle auxiliary routes and outlets, seems is not replaceable.